# jenkins configure page freezes showing "LOADING"

Tags: jenkins

i have installed jenkins 1.466.2 behind apache tomcat and then when i try to access the configure System page it freezes as "loading"

i get the following log

```
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:46 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:46 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 37425
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:46 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
 Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
 INFO: Prepared all plugins
 Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
 INFO: Listed all plugins
 Oct 01, 2012 1:19:37 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
 INFO: Plugin artifactdeployer.jpi is disabled
 Oct 01, 2012 1:19:36 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
 INFO: Plugin artifactory.jpi is disabled
 Oct 01, 2012 1:19:36 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
 INFO: Started initialization
```

Answer (score -3):

Depending upon the number of plugins and jobs you have it on our Jenkins, it will consume some time to boot up. Be patience.

```
Dec 17, 2012 12:04:03 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
Dec 17, 2012 12:04:03 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 17, 2012 12:04:03 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
**INFO: Started initialization**

Dec 17, 2012 12:12:37 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 17, 2012 12:12:38 PM hudson.plugins.greenballs.PluginImpl start
INFO: Green Balls!
Dec 17, 2012 12:12:38 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 17, 2012 12:12:39 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 17, 2012 12:12:39 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 17, 2012 12:12:54 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
```